# Python: BeautifulSoup adding words from an HTML paragraph tag to list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been working on trying to learn web scraping with BeautifulSoup. I am trying to make a Hangman game to learn Python and wanted to make a single-player mode that uses the top 1000 most common words in the English language. I was originally just going to copy-paste each word and run through a list (that is why there is that while loop) but decided to try BeautifulSoup instead.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#words = []
#while True:
    #word = input("Enter the word: ")
    #words.append(word)
    #print(words)

page = requests.get("https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-vocabulary/top-1000-words/") 
resources/english-vocabulary/top-1000-words/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
para = soup.find(class_="field-item even")
```

I am not quite sure where to go from here. I am trying to append all those items from the website (located in the second paragraph tag in the class feild-item even) into a list separately and then save that list as a package to use in the main Hangman game. Since the words appear in the second paragraph tag I am not sure how to do this. I watch a few YouTube videos but they all deal with text that either has an id or another class to call on. Thanks

Comment: Is the link split in two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Words are in second `<p>` so use `para.find_all("p")[1]` to get it.

And then you can get `.text` from this tag - and it has all words in one string.

String has tabs which you should remove - `.replace("\t", "")` and then you can `.split("\n")` to create list with words.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-vocabulary/top-1000-words/") 

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
para = soup.find(class_="field-item even")

second_p = para.find_all('p')[1]
text = second_p.text.replace('\t', '')
words = text.split('\n')
print(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a quick solution for you. You just need to find the correct div, then select the correct child tag that contains the words. Because of the formatting, the words need to be stripped of white space and placed in a list. [Furas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60405929/python-beautifulsoup-adding-words-from-an-html-paragraph-tag-to-list/60406040#60406040) describes that process in more detail.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Hangman:

    def run_game(self):
        word_bank = self.get_word_bank()
        while True:
            # Your game here

    def get_word_bank(self):
        page = requests.get("https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-vocabulary/top-1000-words/", verify=False)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
        words_tag = soup.find('div', {'class': "field-item even"})
        word_bank = words.split(", ".join(words_tag.findChildren()[1].getText().split()))
        return word_bank

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hangman = Hangman()
    hangman.run_game()
```